# Code is not publishing after adding new component in Angular with Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, publish

I am new to angular. I am using asp.net core with Angular. i think it is not related to asp.net core but just telling you guys the framework i am using with angular.

if i just add a new project of asp.net core with angular and publish it. It is sucesfully publishing. When i add new component to src. It don't. i am not sure what i am missing: process i am following to a new component:

1. add a new folder under **app**
2. add type script file and html file.

Type Script file code is :

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ram',
  templateUrl: './ram.component.html',
  template: `<div>
<p>Cached date {{datetimes.dateFormatted}}</p>
<p>Today is {{datetimes.today | date}}</p>
<p>Or if you prefer, {{datetimes.today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
<p>The time is {{datetimes.today | date:'jmZ'}}</p>
<p>Finally the date and time is {{datetimes.today | date:'short'}}</p>
 </div>`
})
export class ramComponent {
  public datetimes: datttimeEntity;
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
http.get<datttimeEntity>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/DatetimeCache').subscribe(result => {
  this.datetimes = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
interface datttimeEntity {
  dateFormatted: Time;
  today: Time;
}
```

HTML page code is :

```
  <h1>testttt</h1>
  {{ datetimes.dateFormatted }}
  <br />
{{datetimes.today}}
```

from API I am just returning two dates. It runs perfectly in debug mode. when I trying to publish the code I got an error, following error:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS1219  (TS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.    Hallis.WEB  G:\test\test\test\ClientApp\src\app\ram\ram.component.ts    17  Active
**

and **Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "npm run build -- --prod" exited with code 1.   Hallis.WEB  G:\Projects\test\test\test\test.csproj  56
**
please help me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: what is `baseUrl` ? Can't you handle it within the `environment` files, that are made for it ?

Comment: @trichetriche, is it related to that error.. ?

Comment: Well you have two decorators, and the first one doesn't seem to have any error, so I guess that yes, it is the error.

Comment: same code is coming with default application and that is publishing perfectly

Comment: Remove the `@Inject` and try ?

Comment: no, still same.. :(

Comment: Exact same error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176638/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-trichetriche).

Comment: @trichetriche, yes same error

Comment: restart VisualStudio :)